# HTOP nice level mismatch with the nice command?

Tags: htop, nice

I executed some commands with `nice -20` but in `htop` the NI appears in red and as 19, why is this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Note that I executed a script with parallel and I also used ```nice -20``` on it, as well as commands in the script

Comment: what was the command you used to set niceness?

Comment: `nice -20 vi` shows as green 20 in htop on MacOS Sierra.

Answer (score 10):

The “nice” value ranges from -20 (top priority, not nice at all to other processes) to 19 (least priority, very nice to others). When you run `nice -20` (equivalent to `nice -n 20`) or `sudo nice -n -42` (equivalent to `sudo nice --42`) or any other value out of bounds, the nice value is moved to the bound.

The red is simply coloring applied to negative values in that column, indicating high-priority (“not nice”) processes. Positive values are green, indicating low-priority (“nice”) processes.

Comment: So since I used ```nice -20``` it defaulted to least priority?

Comment: Yes, `nice -20` or `nice -19` or `nice -99999999` means the least priority which is 19.

Comment: So I should use something like ```nice +20``` to get max priority?

Comment: Only root can increase the priority of a process.

Comment: This is not correct. nice -n -20 should set the niceness ro -20, not +19

Comment: @cristi I'm confused, what is not correct? Are you confusing `nice -20` and `nice -n -20`? `nice -20` is equivalent to `nice -n 20`. Yes, it's a bit confusing to have the `-` sign switch from being an option marker to a minus sign.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said that niceness <-20 will go to 19

Comment: `nice -X` is equivalent to `nice -n X`, where `X` is the nice value. To have max priority, i.e. a nice-value of `-20`, you can use `nice --20` or `nice -n -20`. Min priority, i.e. a nice-value of +19, you can achieve with `nice -19` or `nice -n 19`. It is confusing as long as one understands that the first `-` denotes just a command line option to `nice` and is not a sign for the number. The second `-`, if present, is the minus sign for the number.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are mistaken and didn't set niceness to -20.

If you executed the command as a normal user, for -x you will get 0 instead. For values >20 you will get 20.

If running as root, for values <-20, you will get -20.

Testing as normal user:

```
$ nice -n -20 sleep 100
nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied

# ps ax -o pid,ni,cmd | grep "sleep 100"
26349   0 sleep 100
```

Testing as root:

```
$ sudo nice -n -200 sleep 100

# ps ax -o pid,ni,cmd | grep "sleep 100"
28118   0 sudo nice -n -200 sleep 100
28119 -20 sleep 100
```

Comment: The question stated `nice -20`, which is the opposite of `nice -n 20`.

Comment: @Gilles `-n` adjusts the Nice value by the amount following it, so `nice -n 20` adds, just like `nice -20` does (the `-` denotes a parameter there, not a negative value).

Comment: A red value in `htop` means it's negative, so either the "red 19" was green (as indicated by the Unix `nice` range), OP used `nice -n -20`, or MacOS Sierra has different `nice` and/or `htop` behavior (-20 to 20 nice values is one).